# @font-face styling not working

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have put my @font-face styling in my css with a font that I downloaded and it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Quicksand";
src: url("fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand-Light.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

The font is called Quicksand and it is in my directory (a folder inside of where my index.html and main.css files are located) under a folder called "fonts" and there is a folder within this folder called "Quicksand", and the font that I want to use for the page is inside of this folder and its called "Quicksand-Light.otf".

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Why don't you use [google font](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Quicksand) for that?

Comment: I think if you get rid of the "format" after your src it should work. Src should just have the url and thats it.

Comment: how do you use the font in your site's CSS?

Comment: @la1ch3 That didn't appear to work, sorry. I thought that you always had to declare what format the font is in after the src, is this not true?

Comment: `body{font-family: "Quicksand";}` did you use this on body or div that you wonna use it?

Comment: I don't mind using googlefont for this if I can, but I have no idea how to do it. The last site that I did had the @font-face organized exactly the way that I have it above and it worked well. I don't know what it is that I'm missing....

Comment: Well, next time you'll be able to use it with just a few of clicks + copy/paste. The guide is pretty clear https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Quicksand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the method with the deepest support possible right now. The @font-face rule should be added to the stylesheet before any styles.

Ideal CSS should be like this

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Then use it to style elements like this:

```
body {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

checkout browser support and detail use https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Answer (score 1):

Use google font, Just add below to head tag :

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`